# Extract file from .xsn using c#

Tags: c#, infopath

I need to extract file (template.xml) from .xsn (InfoPath form template) using C#.

How can I do this? I tried to do it using "DotnetZip" and "Microsoft System.IO.Compression.DeflateSteam" but it doesn't work.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to need to explain a little more what "it doesn't work" actually means before anybody can offer you any kind of insight into how to fix the issue.  Without knowing what's going wrong it's going to be almost impossible.  Post some code and give us an idea of which bit isn't working

Comment: I've posted a solution [here][1] which doesn't require external libraries.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533105/minimum-c-sharp-code-to-extract-from-cab-archives-or-infopath-xsn-files-in-mem

Comment: you can see this solution that i use it, maybe 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088172/create-infopath-instance-from-xsn-template

Comment: you can see [this solution][1] that i use it, maybe useful for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088172/create-infopath-instance-from-xsn-template

Comment: you can use below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088172/create-infopath-instance-from-xsn-template

Comment: use can use below solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533105/minimum-c-sharp-code-to-extract-from-cab-archives-or-infopath-xsn-files-in-mem

Answer (score 1):

XSN is not a Zip file, it is CAB.

Here is a blog article talking about manipulation of XSN in JavaScript - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2004/05/04/126147.aspx and another one with some samples I've never used http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/58d9cf34-9a43-4d58-96c7-44bff69ca5d4.

I've used "Unpack XSN file using extract.exe utility to the local temporary directory".

(Search for "C# cab extract" http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+cab+extract for more code samples)