# Minimum C# code to extract from .CAB archives or InfoPath XSN files, in memory

Tags: c#, zip, unmanaged, infopath

Lately I've been trying to implement some functionality which extracts files from an InfoPath XSN file (a .CAB archive). After extensive searching around the internet, it seems that there is no native .NET API for this. All current solutions are centered around large libraries i.e. managed C++ which wrap up Cabinet.dll.

All of this, sadly, falls foul of my companies "No third party libraries" policy.

As of 2.0, .NET gained an attribute called UnmanagedFunctionPointer which allows source level callback declarations using __cdecl. Prior to this, __stdcall was the only show in town, unless you didn't mind fudging the IL, a practice also outlawed here. I immediately knew this would allow the implementation of a fairly small C# wrapper for Cabinet.dll, but I couldn't find an example of one anywhere.

Does anyone know of a cleaner way than the below to do this with native code?

My current solution (executes unmanaged code, but fully working, Tested on 32/64-bit):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CabinetInfo //Cabinet API: "FDCABINETINFO"
{
    public int cbCabinet;
    public short cFolders;
    public short cFiles;
    public short setID;
    public short iCabinet;
    public int fReserve;
    public int hasprev;
    public int hasnext;
}

public class CabExtract : IDisposable
{
    //If any of these classes end up with a different size to its C equivilent, we end up with crash and burn.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class CabError //Cabinet API: "ERF"
    {
        public int erfOper;
        public int erfType;
        public int fError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private class FdiNotification //Cabinet API: "FDINOTIFICATION"
    {
        public int cb;
        public string psz1;
        public string psz2;
        public string psz3;
        public IntPtr userData;
        public IntPtr hf;
        public short date;
        public short time;
        public short attribs;
        public short setID;
        public short iCabinet;
        public short iFolder;
        public int fdie;
    }

    private enum FdiNotificationType
    {
        CabinetInfo,
        PartialFile,
        CopyFile,
        CloseFileInfo,
        NextCabinet,
        Enumerate
    }

    private class DecompressFile
    {
        public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Found { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate IntPtr FdiMemAllocDelegate(int numBytes);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void FdiMemFreeDelegate(IntPtr mem);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate IntPtr FdiFileOpenDelegate(string fileName, int oflag, int pmode);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate Int32 FdiFileReadDelegate(IntPtr hf,
                                              [In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2,
                                                  ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] byte[] buffer, int cb);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate Int32 FdiFileWriteDelegate(IntPtr hf,
                                               [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2,
                                                   ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] byte[] buffer, int cb);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate Int32 FdiFileCloseDelegate(IntPtr hf);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate Int32 FdiFileSeekDelegate(IntPtr hf, int dist, int seektype);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate IntPtr FdiNotifyDelegate(
        FdiNotificationType fdint, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] FdiNotification fdin);

    [DllImport("cabinet.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FDICreate", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern IntPtr FdiCreate(
        FdiMemAllocDelegate fnMemAlloc,
        FdiMemFreeDelegate fnMemFree,
        FdiFileOpenDelegate fnFileOpen,
        FdiFileReadDelegate fnFileRead,
        FdiFileWriteDelegate fnFileWrite,
        FdiFileCloseDelegate fnFileClose,
        FdiFileSeekDelegate fnFileSeek,
        int cpuType,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CabError erf);

    [DllImport("cabinet.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FDIIsCabinet", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern bool FdiIsCabinet(
        IntPtr hfdi,
        IntPtr hf,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CabinetInfo cabInfo);

    [DllImport("cabinet.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FDIDestroy", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern bool FdiDestroy(IntPtr hfdi);

    [DllImport("cabinet.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FDICopy", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern bool FdiCopy(
        IntPtr hfdi,
        string cabinetName,
        string cabinetPath,
        int flags,
        FdiNotifyDelegate fnNotify,
        IntPtr fnDecrypt,
        IntPtr userData);

    private readonly FdiFileCloseDelegate _fileCloseDelegate;
    private readonly FdiFileOpenDelegate _fileOpenDelegate;
    private readonly FdiFileReadDelegate _fileReadDelegate;
    private readonly FdiFileSeekDelegate _fileSeekDelegate;
    private readonly FdiFileWriteDelegate _fileWriteDelegate;
    private readonly FdiMemAllocDelegate _femAllocDelegate;
    private readonly FdiMemFreeDelegate _memFreeDelegate;

    private readonly CabError _erf;
    private readonly List<DecompressFile> _decompressFiles;
    private readonly byte[] _inputData;
    private IntPtr _hfdi;
    private bool _disposed;
    private const int CpuTypeUnknown = -1;

    public CabExtract(byte[] inputData)
    {
        _fileReadDelegate = FileRead;
        _fileOpenDelegate = InputFileOpen;
        _femAllocDelegate = MemAlloc;
        _fileSeekDelegate = FileSeek;
        _memFreeDelegate = MemFree;
        _fileWriteDelegate = FileWrite;
        _fileCloseDelegate = InputFileClose;
        _inputData = inputData;
        _decompressFiles = new List<DecompressFile>();
        _erf = new CabError();
        _hfdi = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private static IntPtr FdiCreate(
        FdiMemAllocDelegate fnMemAlloc,
        FdiMemFreeDelegate fnMemFree,
        FdiFileOpenDelegate fnFileOpen,
        FdiFileReadDelegate fnFileRead,
        FdiFileWriteDelegate fnFileWrite,
        FdiFileCloseDelegate fnFileClose,
        FdiFileSeekDelegate fnFileSeek,
        CabError erf)
    {
        return FdiCreate(fnMemAlloc, fnMemFree, fnFileOpen, fnFileRead, fnFileWrite,
                         fnFileClose, fnFileSeek, CpuTypeUnknown, erf);
    }

    private static bool FdiCopy(
        IntPtr hfdi,
        FdiNotifyDelegate fnNotify)
    {
        return FdiCopy(hfdi, "<notused>", "<notused>", 0, fnNotify, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private IntPtr FdiContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_hfdi == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                _hfdi = FdiCreate(_femAllocDelegate, _memFreeDelegate, _fileOpenDelegate, _fileReadDelegate, _fileWriteDelegate, _fileCloseDelegate, _fileSeekDelegate, _erf);
                if (_hfdi == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to create FDI context.");
            }
            return _hfdi;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (_hfdi != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                FdiDestroy(_hfdi);
                _hfdi = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private IntPtr NotifyCallback(FdiNotificationType fdint, FdiNotification fdin)
    {
        switch (fdint)
        {
            case FdiNotificationType.CopyFile:
                return OutputFileOpen(fdin);
            case FdiNotificationType.CloseFileInfo:
                return OutputFileClose(fdin);
            default:
                return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    private IntPtr InputFileOpen(string fileName, int oflag, int pmode)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(_inputData);
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(stream);
        return (IntPtr)gch;
    }

    private int InputFileClose(IntPtr hf)
    {
        var stream = StreamFromHandle(hf);
        stream.Close();
        ((GCHandle)(hf)).Free();
        return 0;
    }

    private IntPtr OutputFileOpen(FdiNotification fdin)
    {
        var extractFile = _decompressFiles.Where(ef => ef.Name == fdin.psz1).SingleOrDefault();

        if (extractFile != null)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(stream);
            extractFile.Handle = (IntPtr)gch;
            return extractFile.Handle;
        }

        //Don't extract
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private IntPtr OutputFileClose(FdiNotification fdin)
    {
        var extractFile = _decompressFiles.Where(ef => ef.Handle == fdin.hf).Single();
        var stream = StreamFromHandle(fdin.hf);

        extractFile.Found = true;
        extractFile.Length = (int)stream.Length;

        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            extractFile.Data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.Read(extractFile.Data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        stream.Close();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private int FileRead(IntPtr hf, byte[] buffer, int cb)
    {
        var stream = StreamFromHandle(hf);
        return stream.Read(buffer, 0, cb);
    }

    private int FileWrite(IntPtr hf, byte[] buffer, int cb)
    {
        var stream = StreamFromHandle(hf);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, cb);
        return cb;
    }

    private static Stream StreamFromHandle(IntPtr hf)
    {
        return (Stream)((GCHandle)hf).Target;
    }

    private IntPtr MemAlloc(int cb)
    {
        return Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cb);
    }

    private void MemFree(IntPtr mem)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mem);
    }

    private int FileSeek(IntPtr hf, int dist, int seektype)
    {
        var stream = StreamFromHandle(hf);
        return (int)stream.Seek(dist, (SeekOrigin)seektype);
    }

    public bool ExtractFile(string fileName, out byte[] outputData, out int outputLength)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("CabExtract");

        var fileToDecompress = new DecompressFile();
        fileToDecompress.Found = false;
        fileToDecompress.Name = fileName;

        _decompressFiles.Add(fileToDecompress);

        FdiCopy(FdiContext, NotifyCallback);

        if (fileToDecompress.Found)
        {
            outputData = fileToDecompress.Data;
            outputLength = fileToDecompress.Length;
            _decompressFiles.Remove(fileToDecompress);
            return true;
        }

        outputData = null;
        outputLength = 0;
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsCabinetFile(out CabinetInfo cabinfo)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("CabExtract");

        var stream = new MemoryStream(_inputData);
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(stream);

        try
        {
            var info = new CabinetInfo();
            var ret = FdiIsCabinet(FdiContext, (IntPtr)gch, info);
            cabinfo = info;
            return ret;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
            gch.Free();
        }
    }

    public static bool IsCabinetFile(byte[] inputData, out CabinetInfo cabinfo)
    {
        using (var decomp = new CabExtract(inputData))
        {
            return decomp.IsCabinetFile(out cabinfo);
        }
    }

    //In an ideal world, this would take a stream, but Cabinet.dll seems to want to open the input several times.
    public static bool ExtractFile(byte[] inputData, string fileName, out byte[] outputData, out int length)
    {
        using (var decomp = new CabExtract(inputData))
        {
            return decomp.ExtractFile(fileName, out outputData, out length);
        }
    }

    //TODO: Add methods for enumerating/extracting multiple files
}
```

Comment: Interesting. If this is working code, rather than a question (which you indicate it is), consider putting this up as a (smallish) "project" on [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com) or [github](http://github.com), preferably with some tests.

Comment: Thought about it, but what I really wanted in the first place was a small "Copy/Paste" job from stackoverflow, not a project, so this is what I'm giving back

Comment: Fair enough and appreciated, however you might get a "not a real question" close on this one. SO is a Q/A type of site, so you could write a (phony) question and provide your own answer. Personally, I don't bother, others may.

Comment: "my companies "No third party libraries" policy" - I hope you challenge this on a regular basis. How likely is it that the company's developers are going to be the best able to write every type of component? Are going to understand the nuances of all kinds of problem domains that are nothing to do with your company's actual business?

Comment: > I hope you challenge this on a regular basis

About 3 times a week. There are some positive aspects of re-inventing the wheel on a daily basis, i.e. I learn some real nuts and bolts stuff, and get paid to do it. I certainly did here. I have to say, writing this was far more interesting that messing with InfoPath forms.

Comment: This isn't a question.  You might paste your code on codereview.se instead, they welcome working code and suggest further improvements.

Comment: in which context is this code running? is this a standalone app or is this embedded within infopath?

Comment: I guess you could run it anywhere. Initially I had it in a standalone Winforms app, but its ultimate destination is now a ASP.NET app.

Comment: How is cabinet.dll a third party library? You use kernel32.dll right? Of course you do. You guys wrote your own C# runtime too? :)

Comment: For academic interest, you could open the `Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll` that ships with the Wix Toolset in a decompiler . Specifically the `CabUnpacker` class.

Comment: Can you please show how you are using the code above?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use other libraries created by Microsoft?  It doesn't come with the framework but there is a MS library for working with Cab files:

Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab

It can be used as follows

```
CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(@"C:\data.cab");
cab.Unpack(@"C:\ExtractDir");
```

Answer (score 0):

We also have the "no third party libs" policy (pain that it is). Yet we need to "unroll" IP forms for various reasons. Our solution was to use CABARC (which is an exe but from Microsoft, and it used to be included in Windows installation although might not be anymore). It can be scripted in any language from a shell, we use vbs or powershell. It works just like any zip/unzip program with command line switches.

Just another option for those finding the good information from above.

Comment: Interesting, but that will extract to the file system; not to in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding CAB files is identical to expanding ZIP files.

You can find some code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b5bde5fa-f63a-41e0-8569-c75d2f61e76b)

Comment: The snip you've posted is using java.util.zip.ZipFile. Even if this can open a .CAB file, it's not a solution that runs on a system with no third party libraries installed, which defeats the original objective.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:
[How to extract a file from a .CAB file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/58d9cf34-9a43-4d58-96c7-44bff69ca5d4/)
I mean the proposal of [JohnWein](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/johnwein/?ws=usercard-mini) (an MCC) there.
What you do then with the files - whether you copy them in a target directoty, as in the foreach statemant of the referenced example, or just use them in memory - is up to you then.
*(I guess this is what **Alexandru-Dan** meant as well - if you're not looking at the question but the answer there instead.)*

If this approach does work in your scenario then it's a much more simpler solution - without any 3rd party dll.

Does it?

Answer (score -1):

If the concern is with 3rd party binary libraries, I can't help, but there are open source ZIP libraries that will open a CAB file.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: The ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib documentation doesn't mention CAB files at all. So unless you can give a code example, this answer isn't very useful.