# How to convert/transform XML to XSN?

Tags: xml, infopath

Does anyone knows how to convert/transform .XML file to .XSN file? Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an InfoPath XML, you can not just convert it to an XSN (the InfoPath solution file).  However, if you published the InfoPath form to a SharePoint form library, you can download the XSN solution file by going to the SharePoint form library, choosing Form Library Settings, then Advanced Settings and "(Edit Template)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to convert, but no direct way. Please refer the following link:

[How to create .xsn (InfoPath) file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20916394/1437877)